# Is it possible to Ingeset file content using FSCrawler to perticular _id of existing index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, fscrawler

I have already ingested data to the existing Elasticsearch index with _id as one of the column name "mainid" value in database. Now I have another table in that I have two columns "mainid" and path to the files. I want to ingest these files using fSCrawler  into the existing Elasticsearch index and files should get ingested into corresponding _id.

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` is generated from the filename by FSCrawler. If you want to provide your own `_id`, for the time being, you need to use the [REST service](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/rest.html) instead.

It allows you to [provide the `_id` you want](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/rest.html#document-id). Like:

```
echo "This is my text" > test.txt
curl -F "file=@test.txt" -F "id=my-test" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/fscrawler/_upload"
```